# DITA-OT 3.6.1: DOTJ083E capitalization errors

Tags: dita, dita-ot

We recently upgraded to DITA-OT 3.6.1 from 3.2.1. We started getting the following types of errors:

```
[map-reader] file:/c:/Temp/<path and file>.ditamap:5:181: [DOTJ083E][ERROR] The resource referenced as file:/c:/Temp/<path and file>.xml is capitalized differently on disk, using file:/C:/Temp/<path and file>.xml.
```

The error seems to refer to the capitalization of the drive letter. What's odd is that we use relative paths in our source files. The only time we specify the drive letter is in the batch file we use to generate our help files with the DITA-OT (which is entered as `c:`).

My questions are:

- Outside of changing the `c:` in the batch file to `C:`, is there any way to fix this error by entering a setting or modifying our plugins?
- Is this error benign, and we can ignore it because it doesn't affect the output?
- Is this something that has been reported as an issue with the DITA-OT?

Thank you for your help.

Matt Stern
Sr. Principal Tech Writer
Kofax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the DITA OT has this check in which it tries to warn you that the publishing might not work on an operating system which is case sensitive (like Linux).
The error is benign on Windows, but it may signal sometimes problems which you may want to correct, for example if you have a link in the DITA content to "topic.dita" but the file name is actually "Topic.dita", this works on Windows but would not work when published on Linux.

There is a "processing-mode" transformation parameter which can probably be set to "skip" to avoid seeing this problem but in my opinion it is best to change the temp directory specified in the configuration to have the upper cased drive letter.